# Play teaser for 10 sec in iframe tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, iframe

I want to play a teaser of 10 sec in iframe tag which has src of both **youtube** and **livestream** in my cordova app.
after teaser the video should stop and it should not play beyond 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

While embedding youtube video you can set start and end times of the embedded video.

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/0Bmhjf0rKe8?start=0&end=10
```

should work in your case

Comment: Livestream by ffmpeg stream? Or is it like youtube?

Comment: https://livestream.com/accounts/1497761/events/6420093/videos/137335725/pla…dth=640&height=360&enableInfo=true&autoPlay=true&mute=false

Comment: above is the url of livestream like youtube only

Comment: Since it is a premium service, I couldn't find much information. It seems they don't have any similar feature: https://help.livestream.com/hc/en-us/articles/219100767-How-Do-I-Embed-My-Event- I would suggest using JavaScript but it would be very complicated

Comment: can you give example for using javascript for this?

Comment: You need to attach to livestream player's events. If it is a Flash player you can't do anything. If it is an HTML5 video player you can attach to its events and detect how many seconds have been played.

Comment: In short, Google it: HTML5 video events and methods